# How to create an array of Message type

Tags: c++, arrays, protocol-buffers

The C++ project I have been working on is using Google's protobuf for their data representation and its sort of already created protos file and its been compiled to get away with `.cc` and `.h`.Now my question is can I create an array of my message type

```
class MyMessage : public ::google::protobuf::Message {
...;
....;
}
```

Because it seems that `MyMessage` type  generated by the Proto compiler doesn't implement any of the array counterparts like `[]`,so will it be ok when i do things like

`MyMessage * array = new MyMessage[4];`
or
using STL is the only choice;

Answer (score 2):

```
MyMessage array = new MyMessage[4];
```

You can't do this as `array` is a variable of type `MyMessage`, but `new MyMessage[4]` gives you a `MyMessage*` (*pointer to an array of `MyMessage`s*).

You could do either

```
MyMessage array[4];
```

or

```
MyMessage *array = new MyMessage[4];
```

Comment: Alexander Aleksandrovič Klimov I appreciate, i just made a typography the * should be there when  new is there, but my question is a bit differ from array declaration what i am lookin for is whether i get support from the compiler generated` MyMessage` if i ever  intended to create an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create arrays of *any* complete type. (You should have a header file with the class definition.)